maltipoo and kitty
I've recently got a new kitty after two or three weeks of close door sniffing and viewing our vet gave us the go and we started doing face-to-face with a leash my dog is more interested in food than the cat but when the kitten touches our dog she gets excited and either backs up sits and lets a whine out or pokes at the cat with her nose I don't really know if shes tryna play or wants to nip at the kitten and eat it

What's your question?  A nise poke is usually not hostile.

just if these are signs of hostility  my dog gets excited very quickly and  I wouldn't want her to hurt the kitty yk to clarify I'm not sure if she trying to nip at the kitty or just poke and get its attention

This is a textbook example of dog trying to play.
